# Encoding double nested JSON body for swift HTTP API request

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

Digging into HTTP requested in swift, and struggling on what seems to be a more difficult one. Below is the POST body request data.

```
{
"data": {
    "slices": [
      {
        "origin": "DFW",
        "destination": "ACT",
        "departure_date": "2021-07-01"
      }
    ],
    "passengers": [
      {
        "type": "adult"
        
      },
      {
        "type": "adult"
      }
    ],
    "cabin_class": "economy"
  }
}
```

I'm experiencing issues with encoding the data in swift in this form:

```
struct data:Codable{
    
    struct Slices: Codable{
        var origin:String
        var destination:String
        var departure_date:String
    }
    

    struct Passengers:Codable {
        var type:String
    }
    
    var slices:[Slices]
    var passengers:[Passengers]
    var cabin_class:String
    
    
}
class offercall {
    func getposts() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.duffel.com/air/offer_requests") else {return}
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("beta", forHTTPHeaderField: "Duffel-Version")
        request.setValue("Bearer [redacted]: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(data)
          
        }
```

Getting an error that the data.type cannot conform to "Encodable". Likely, I have it formatted wrong but not sure how to adjust for the JSON format. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

The new full code is below, and is striking an error in the JSONEncoder() line.

```
import Foundation


struct bodypayload: Encodable {
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Encodable {
    let slices: [Slice]
    let passengers: [Passenger]
    let cabinClass: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case slices, passengers
        case cabinClass = "cabin_class"
    }
}

// MARK: - Passenger
struct Passenger: Encodable {
    let type: String
}

// MARK: - Slice
struct Slice: Encodable {
    let origin, destination, departureDate: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case origin, destination
        case departureDate = "departure_date"
    }
}

class offercall {
    func getposts() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.duffel.com/air/offer_requests") else {return}
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("beta", forHTTPHeaderField: "Duffel-Version")
        request.setValue("Bearer duffel_test_erpW6O-b1V-mNBCn7GOHlQgB7Srx_nGa4_w_0IfQvDW", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(bodypayload)
        
    }
```

Comment: You are capitalizing the first character of the names of the Struct models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuckType is your friend https://app.quicktype.io

```
//   let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

struct Result: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let slices: [Slice]
    let passengers: [Passenger]
    let cabinClass: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case slices, passengers
        case cabinClass = "cabin_class"
    }
}

struct Passenger: Codable {
    let type: String
}

struct Slice: Codable {
    let origin, destination, departureDate: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case origin, destination
        case departureDate = "departure_date"
    }
}
```

This works just fine:

```
func example(result: Result) -> URLRequest? {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.duffel.com/air/offer_requests") else { return nil }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("beta", forHTTPHeaderField: "Duffel-Version")
    request.setValue("Bearer [redacted]", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(result)
    return request
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is super cool, thank you for passing that along. It does still seem to draw an error when using the JSON Encoder in the request.httpBody . "Type 'bodyrequest' cannot conform to 'Encodable'

Comment: What is the type of `bodyrequest`? Because the request I outline above compiles just fine.

Comment: It is a POST request, its a custom request via application/json type. Apologies if I was misunderstanding that question

Comment: The code above creates a POST request and compiles just fine. What are you doing differently?

Comment: The new full code is added above, and the error occurs whether the struct are marked as Codable or Encodable

Comment: Also, still receiving the encodable error with the above revised you had provided.
1. Only concrete types such as structs, enums and classes can conform to protocols
2. Required by instance method 'encode' where 'T' = 'bodypayload.Type'

Comment: You can't encode a type. You have to create an object to encode. How are you changing the code I provided? It compiles fine as it is.

Comment: Just a mistype error, that was a stellar procedure, and a great help, thank you!